# Is there a way to fetch all facebook events that atleast one of my friends is attending?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can I fetch all Facebook events that atleast one of my friends is attending? All I need is event IDs nothing else. Will Facebook let me fetch that info?
Also, i have never run any code with facebook api, could you tell me whays the most simple environment i can use to send this query?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer: No, of course not. Since v2.0, all friend permissions have been removed.

There is one way though, you can store the attended events of an authorized user and show the info to a friend who authorized the App too.

About how to start with the Facebook API, please start reading the docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs

Comment: Why is it so? Assuming i can view their events manually by going to their page, why is it impossible to do via the API?

Comment: because that´s just how it is. third party apps have no business with data of users who did not authorize their app. just because it´s visible on facebook does not mean you can grab it with the api.

Comment: If thats the case, how do you explain that i know an app (tinder) that can tell me when i see someone that is a friend of a friend of a friend of mine, or a "2nd" friend as they call it? (that is, it accesses all of my friends friends-list and see if someone in these lists is a friend of the person i am currently viewing)

Comment: first of all, the upgrade to v2.0 is still happening, tinder may not be upgraded yet. 2nd degree friends? never saw those on tinder. but of course tinder may store the friend lists and compare them. nothing wrong with that. but that´s off topic anyway.

Comment: 1. What do you mean by "tinder may store the friend lists and compare them"? I mean, to store the friend lists of my friends, I have to access it. Which you said is impossible for third-party apps to grab data of users who did not authorize them. Or you mean it only stores the friendlists of people who have installed tinder? 2. What do you mean by that tinder may not have upgraded to V2.0? If tinder can use an older version of the API, why I cannot do it too my self?

Comment: they can get the friends who authorized the app and store those. they can do that if your friend logs in. then they can compare the data.
this is going way too far away from the topic, but facebook did not just upgrade all apps at once from v1.0 to v2.0, it´s a process that is happening since end of april 2015 and afaik it is still going on.

Comment: meaning: forget about v1.0, you cannot use it anymore. my answer is 100% correct btw.